# Hiding / Showing Kendo grid scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to show my kendo grid's scrollbar only if it's necessary. Here is my grid initialization:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<UT.Repo.Core.up_HedgedCustomerLatestTradeListGet_Result>()
    .Name("lastPositionsGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ACCOUNT).Title("Hesap").Width(70);
        columns.Bound(c => c.TICKET).Title("Emir");
        columns.Bound(c => c.SIDE).Title("Yön").Width(50);
        columns.Bound(c => c.STATE).Title("Durum").Width(65);
        columns.Bound(c => c.SYMBOL).Title("Sembol");
        columns.Bound(c => c.VOLUME).Title("Hacim").Width(65);
        columns.Bound(c => c.OPENPX).Title("Açılış");
        columns.Bound(c => c.CLOSEPX).Title("Kapanış");
        columns.Bound(c => c.P_L).Title("Kar Zarar").Width(75);
        columns.Bound(c => c.SL).Title("Zararı Durdur");
        columns.Bound(c => c.TP).Title("Karı Al");
        columns.Bound(c => c.TIME).Title("Zaman").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(TIME, \"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss\") #").Width(160);
    })
    .Scrollable()
    .Sortable()
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("onLastPositionsGridDataBound"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("TIME").Descending())
        .Read(read => read.Action("HedgedCustomerLatestTradeListGet", "Home"))
    )
)
```

On data bound I'm trying to set visibility of scrollbar:

```
function onLastPositionsGridDataBound(e) {
    var gridHeight = $("#lastPositionsGrid").outerHeight();
    var gridHeaderHeight = $("#lastPositionsGrid table:eq(0)").outerHeight();
    var gridBodyHeight = $("#lastPositionsGrid table:eq(1)").outerHeight();
    if (gridHeight < gridHeaderHeight + gridBodyHeight) { // show the scrollbar
        $("#lastPositionsGrid .k-grid-header").css('padding', '');
        $("#lastPositionsGrid .k-grid-header").css('padding-right', '17px');
        $("#lastPositionsGrid .k-grid-content").css('overflow-y','scroll');
    }
    else { // hide the scrollbar
        $("#lastPositionsGrid .k-grid-header").css('padding','0 !important');
        $("#lastPositionsGrid .k-grid-content").css('overflow-y', 'visible');
    }
}
```

The part that hides the scrollbar does its work nicely but the part that shows the scrollbar does not. Here is a screenshot after showing the scrollbar:

[image]

As you see the lines those separate the cells in header and the rows does not fit. How can I fix it?

Comment: I'll give you a simple 'hacker' answer.  If you have code that can correctly decide when to hide 'the scroll bar', but can't correctly decide when to show 'the scroll bar' the solution is obvious.  Always show the scroll-bar, THEN run your code to decide if you should hide it.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps you.

Answer (score 3):

this will work, try overflow auto always.

```
function onLastPositionsGridDataBound(e) {
    var gridHeight = $("#lastPositionsGrid").outerHeight();
    var gridHeaderHeight = $("#lastPositionsGrid table:eq(0)").outerHeight();
    var gridBodyHeight = $("#lastPositionsGrid table:eq(1)").outerHeight();
    if (gridHeight < gridHeaderHeight + gridBodyHeight) { // show the scrollbar
        $("#lastPositionsGrid .k-grid-header").css('padding', '');
        $("#lastPositionsGrid .k-grid-header").css('padding-right', '17px');
        $("#lastPositionsGrid .k-grid-content").css('overflow-y','auto');
    }
    else { // hide the scrollbar
        $("#lastPositionsGrid .k-grid-header").css('padding','0 !important');
        $("#lastPositionsGrid .k-grid-content").css('overflow-y', 'auto');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is the way to go. However, wouldn't one line of CSS make this entire function unnecessary? `#lastPositionsGrid .k-grid-content {overflow: auto}`

Comment: ya in CSS it's minimal

Comment: But this does not solve the problem. Please see the screenshot I added. I'm getting the same result

Answer (score 2):

I just changed two things in your javascript and it worked like charm. Thanks

1. Changing the value from `17px` to `21px`. So basically you have to find the right value of padding-right.
2. Changing the value from `'0 !important'` to `'0px'`. To fix the header to not show an extra column at the end.

[image: No Scrollbar]

[image: With Scrollbar]

Comment: This version does not hide the scrollbar in my case. Did you do something else?

Comment: try the different possible values of overflow. overflow-y hidden should do the trick.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your problem. If yes how wer you able to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a simple 'hacker' answer.  If you have code that can correctly decide when to hide 'the scroll bar', but can't correctly decide when to show 'the scroll bar' the solution is obvious.  Always show the scroll-bar, THEN run your code to decide if you should hide it.

Comment: Hi hacker! Thanks for your answer but the problem is not about deciding when to show or hide the scrollbar. The script decides that correctly. As you see the grid's datasource is refreshed by ajax calls. So I need to have a few lines of code for both of the states: showed to hidden, hidden to showed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are manually setting the scroll bar to the grid, The grid has no idea about that change. So you can fix it by just autoFit the column once you are done with showing or hiding the scroll bar. So inside your function `onLastPositionsGridDataBound` after your if and else to set / hide the scroll bar autoFit the columns, So place this code after the if else.

```
 var grid = $("#lastPositionsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
 for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
      grid.autoFitColumn(i);  //autofit each column.
 }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No this does not solve the problem. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, since you can control the **options.scrollable** property you can use something like this on your grid **dataBound**:

```
dataBound: function (e) {
   if (this.dataSource.options.data.length > this.dataSource.pageSize()) {
                this.options.scrollable = true;                    
            }
        }
```

Then you can update the options like this: `grid.setOptions(grid.getOptions());`